# How do you turn off Sitecore ECM processing on CD server?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-ecm

We have a CD and CM server configured.  We want to configure the CM server to process ECM emails.  I cannot find any documentation to turn this off on the CD server.

Does anyone know how to turn this off?

Comment: This question is product related (not network/server) and it either requires adapting the web.config to match the right settings or write C# code in the Sitecore pipelines to get the above mentioned behavior. So I believe it is not really off-topic?

Comment: This is a valid question and should be re-opened.

Comment: Re-opened. But SO questions should really include, what has been attempted to resolve the issue so far - as the question stands right now, it may not be off topic but it is definitely a bit on the "vague" side.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the processors from the `initialize` pipeline and the task agent from the `scheduling` section of `Sitecore.EmailCampaign.config`. You can use a patch config:

```xml
<pipelines>
  <initialize>
    <processor type="Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Presentation.UI.Pipelines.Loader.InitializePresenterBinder, Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Presentation.UI">
      <patch:delete />
    </processor>
    <processor type="Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Presentation.UI.Pipelines.Loader.ConfigurePresenterBinderContainer, Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Presentation.UI">
      <patch:delete />
    </processor>
  </initialize>
</pipelines>
<scheduling>
  <agent hint="ECM">
    <patch:delete />
  </agent>
</scheduling>
```

You also need to make sure the module files and a connectionstring to a web service on CM is added in your CD environment. See section 3.4.2 of the [Email Campaign Manager Developer Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/ecm/210/ecm_administrator_and_developer_guide_21-a4.pdf) for more details.